# Check for a certain value in a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am currently working on a app where i want to check if the particular object exists in the NSDictionary or not. I have tried this code but it does not seem to work. Any help will be appreciated!

```
    for (int i=0; sizeofarray; i++) {
    if ([[self.chat valueForKeyPath:@"text"] count] > 0)
    {
        NSDictionary* chatmessage=[self.chat objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([chatmessage[@"text"] isEqualToString:@"Guest787" ]) {
            NSLog(@"this happened");
        }}
}
```

P.S sizeofarray is the length of the array and chat is the array which is stored in the dictionary.

Comment: The `for` condition, as written, doesn't make any sense.  Please check your actual code to make sure it's correct.

Comment: @avi the code is not correct ,that is the reason i need help.I had no other choice than use a for loop for the objectAtIndex.

Comment: The middle condition doesn't make sense.  If `sizeofarray` is non-zero, it will loop forever.

Comment: Do you want to know *where* (i.e. the index) or just *if* the value exists in the array?

Comment: You must be more clear about what you actually need help with. You say that you want to se if an object exists, but you seem to be checking weather if has a particular value. Meanwhile your problem might actually be a incorrect for-loop.

Comment: @trojanfoe i just want to know if the value exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this task – find a dictionary with a specific key/value pair in an array – a predicate is a suitable solution.

```
NSString *value = @"Guest787";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"text == %@", value];
NSArray *result = [self.chat filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
BOOL valueExists = result.count > 0;
NSLog(@"%d", valueExists);
```

Or with Key-Value Coding (KVC)

```
 BOOL valueExists = [[self.chat valueForKey:@"text"] containsObject:@"Guest787"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ?

```
if ([self.chat containsObject:@"Guest787"]) {
    NSLog(@"this happened");
}
```

OR

```
for (NSString *message in self.chat) {
    if ([message isEqualToString:@"Guest787"]) {
        NSLog(@"this happened");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an array of dictionaries, not strings, so this won't work.

Comment: "chat is the array which is stored in the dictionary."

Comment: He means "`chat` is an array of dictionaries" as evidenced by the code.